# PHP wont insert data into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Before I start, I have looked at other similar questions and done everything on them, yet it still is not working.
I'm creating a register script, and no errors occur, yet none of the submitted data appears in the database.
The database is named 'test' and the table 'users'. 
Here is the form;

```
<body><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<form action="script3.php" method="get">
<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>
<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name" /></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="text" name="pass" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is script3;

```
<?php 
$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test');
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");
$query = ("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', SHA1('$pass'), NOW() );")
?>
```

Comment: remove the **@** in `mysqli_connect` and look again for errors. Also, instead of GET, use POST to insert data

Comment: `@query` is a variable. It doesn't actually run the query.

Comment: Missing semi-colon at the end of `...NOW() );")` --- for one thing.

Comment: Actually using `@mysqli_connect` does work, I tested the OP's code with the fix that was needed, while keeping `@mysqli_connect`. @MathewFoscarini --- It just suppresses any error messages, should there ever be any.

Comment: Sidenote: Change `<input type="text" name="pass" />` to `<input type="password" name="pass" />` otherwise the password will be shown in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, You need to execute the query:

```
$query = ("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', SHA1('$pass'), NOW() );");
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: This is the only one that worked. `+1` ;-)

Comment: Still not working on my system:(

Comment: That's impossible. I tested this and you're obviously doing something wrong. Check your column names, see if they match. @Fabian Plus, you shouldn't be using a `GET` method. Passwords can be seen in the address bar. Use `POST`

Comment: I have a user ID column, will that make a difference and if so how can I produce this?

Comment: Even if you do have a `ID` column and nothing is going in it, that shouldn't matter. If the columns exist, then the values will be inserted. @Fabian

Comment: other than that, the columns match then

Comment: I can't help you anymore than I already have. Far as I'm concerned, this question should be closed. You need to double check everything: Column types, lengths, etc. etc. @Fabian

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll check everything when I get a chance :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually run the SQL query, not just define the query SQL string.

Comment: I do that by mysql_query() right?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test');
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");
$query = ("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', SHA1('$pass'), NOW() );")
    // insert this line, it will work
    mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, thank you anyway

Comment: try it, and see the error then tell what is next
    if (!mysqli_query($query,$dbc))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

Comment: You are missing a parameter. http://php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: I tried the code on there but it did not work

Comment: What was the error, ??? 
paste the error here, and if not wrking
then change mysqli with mysql. it should work

Comment: It's missing an ending semi-colon. Use [`Krish's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21241144/) which worked for me (tested). @Fabian

Answer (score 0):

just pass your query string to mysql_query() function.

```
mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_*` functions, and not `mysql_*`

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you are required to insert only one line.

```
mysqli_query($query,$dbc);
```

and your code is ready now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test');
$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) //@ symbol removed
OR die("could not connect");
$today=Date('Y-m-d');
$query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', SHA1('$pass'), '$today' )";   //() removed , '' added for date
$res=mysqli_query($abc,$query);  //added
?>
```

this will work.

if not working then comment your error message..

Comment: Using quotes around `'NOW()'` will produce `0000-00-00` as a date. By the way, I'm not the downvoting type, it's not my style. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = ("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date) 
VALUES ('".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$email."', SHA1('".$pass."'), NOW() );")

    mysqli_query($query);
```